# Rails enum field not instantiated in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, form-for

I have an enum, `prediction_type` declared this way in the model:

```
enum prediction_type: [:neural_network, :capm]
```

However, when I submit the following form from the view, the other field (`prediction_days`)gets instantiated, while `prediction_type` remains `nil`.

```
<%=form_for @currency do |f| %>
        <%= f.select(:prediction_days, options_for_select(1..30)) %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :prediction_type, value: :neural_network%>
        <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Server log or didn't happen. :P

Comment: value should be a string, without ':'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming enum prediction types is defined under currency model.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :prediction_type, value: Currency.predcition_types[:neural_network] %>
```